# Libgdx Programm works fine as desktop applicaton but doesnt work in html

Tags: java, libgdx, bitmap-fonts

My programm works fine when i start it as desktop application but when i run the superdev and run it in my browser i get an Error below the screen.
The Error message says:

> GwtApplication: exception: font/white.fnt does not exist 
>       font/white.fnt does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is with your font folder.
You can either tell gradle about your font folder (via gradle files), or easier move your font to the assets folder, so your white.fnt file is in the root of assets folder.

```
BitmapFont bf = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("white.fnt"));
```

See, not fonts/white.fnt, because you moved your font file to the assets.

Comment: Now i got one to the splashscreen of my program, than it go stuck, after i started it again i got the same error but now with white.fnt dies not exist

Comment: What 'Now i got one to the splashscreen of my program,' means? Please explain more briefly.

Comment: First when i startet i got instantly a black screen with the error massage and after the changes i got to my splashscreen i made with TweeenEngine but after it faded out my next screen hasnt appeared, and after i started it again go got the error message but without the font/